# Enter login in separate web browser in calabash test

Tags: ios, cucumber

We have an iOS app in development that opens a browser in Safari (and not within the app itself) for login information (username, password, submit button), then returns to the app. So far my Calabash tests have balked at entering any data in these fields. Would I maybe need to do this outside of Calabash, possibly with Watir? Or something else?

Thank you in advance.
Chris Petersen

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible, otwherwise you can open you webview and than pass data with NSURLRequest object:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```